# Accuracy decreasing over epochs using Keras' fit_generator

Tags: python, keras

#### Problem summary:

I'm trying out a basic ANN model on a binary classificaton task. I have arguably big data **total of 2 GB** consists of **150 csv files.** Data consists of 6 features and 1 target.

**Important note:** This is a binary classification task and each file consists of only one label. Eg. file_1 includes only label 0, and file_2 includes only label 1.

**Problem 1:** I use Keras' `fit_generator` method to read data file by file and batch by batch. I start train the model, **but the model gives different results at the end of each training.** Also, sometimes accuracy decreases over time. I think this is because of eacy file includes only one label only.

**Problem 2:** I'm not sure if I wrote the `data_generator` method properly. I need to get data from different CSV files. Any kind of suggestion would be appreciated.

#### Some code

**Simple ANN model:**

```
def create_model():
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(32, kernel_initializer='normal',
                    activation='relu', input_dim=(6)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(16, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(8, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(16, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(32, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss="binary_crossentropy",
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

**Data generator**:
I'm trying to generate data **from different CSV files**

```
def data_generotto(path: str, batchsize: int):
    while True:
        for csv_file in os.listdir(path):
            chunks = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(
                path, csv_file), sep=';', chunksize=batchsize)

            for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
                X, y = preprocess.preprocess(chunk)

                yield (X, y)
```

**Code for getting total size of data:**

```
def get_total_size(path: str):
    for csv_file in os.listdir(path):
        global SIZE
        with open(os.path.join(path, csv_file)) as f:
            for line in f:
                SIZE += 1

            SIZE -= 1 # minus header line
```

**Main program flow:**

```
np.random.seed(7)

SIZE = 0
BS = 1000
EPOCHS = 5

if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = cnn.create_model()

    get_total_size("./complete_csv")
    print("size calculated")

    H = model.fit_generator(data_generotto(
        "./complete_csv", BS), steps_per_epoch=SIZE // BS, epochs=EPOCHS, workers=-1)

    save_model(model, "./MODEL.h5")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my misunderstanding of your problem. Now I have some thoughts about your task:

1. The neural networks fit the high dimension problem well, but your data only have 6 features which is too short for neural networks.
2. Maybe you can try some machine learning methods like decision tree, SVM and some boosting methods. I think these methods will adapt to your task.

Comment: No I meant that I have 150 different files and target value in each file is either 0 or 1. Every file don't have different label.
Have you any suggestion with the data generation process? Is everything seem OK?

Comment: @emremrah Do you have any log during training process, including loss and accuracy?

Comment: Not any specifically defined logs but the `fit_generator`'s verbosity. The accuracies through different training sessions are inconsistent. I just trained a model, and the accuracy on last epoch was %93. The result of previous training session was only %23. I don't understand why